# Overflow: auto working on desktop but not mobile

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a single div scrollable when the text doesn't fit within it. This is working great on desktop but in chrome dev console when I emulate mobile, it won't scroll and the background image for the parent div gets zoomed too. See code below. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Brett

PS: Please forgive the messy code I plan on improving later. This section of the page has been an absolute headache.

```
#description {
    overflow-y: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        
    #results {
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 2vh;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
        grid-row-gap: 2vh;
        grid-auto-flow: row;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        background-image: url(./assets/img/bg_hero_3.svg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

    #results > #description {
        grid-row: 3;
        grid-column: 1 / 4;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }

    #results > div {
        display: grid;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        grid-row-gap: 1vh;
    }
    
    .bubble {
        height: 15vw !important;
        width: 15vw !important;
    }
    
    h6 {
        font-family: ArchitectsDaughter;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 3vw;
        text-align: center;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

    #results {
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80vh;
        padding-top: 0%;
        margin: 0 auto;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        background-image: url(./assets/img/bg_hero_3.svg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }



    #results > #description {
        grid-row: 2;
        grid-column: 1 / 7;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        padding: 10%;
        text-align: center;
        color: white;
        display: block;
    }
    
    #results > div {
        grid-row: 1;
        display: grid;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        align-text: center;
        grid-template-rows: 10vh auto;
    }
    
    h6 {
        font-family: ArchitectsDaughter;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-weight: 700;
        font-size: 2vw;
        text-align: center;
    }

}
```

Comment: Attach your html, we need to reproduce the issue to help you

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out. I needed to set a constant height for the grid (#results) and ALSO the grid-row-template (3rd row). See code below:

```
    #results {
        display: grid;
        width: 100%;
        height: 80vh;
        padding: 2vh;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        grid-template-rows: auto auto 50vh;
        grid-row-gap: 2vh;
        grid-auto-flow: row;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        justify-items: center;
        background-image: url(./assets/img/bg_hero_3.svg);
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```